# SkyDrive Sync Problems on Windows 8.1

Tags: sync, onedrive, windows-8.1-preview

I am having some trouble with SkyDrive On Windows 8.1.  First of all, there is no SkyDrive icon in the bottom-right corner of the taskbar, even when I click the up arrow.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling SkyDrive, but it never appeared.

Another thing is that it does not sync to skydrive.com. My App and desktop folder are always synced.  And whenever I open a file from skydrive directly from an Office Application, the folder is synced with skydrive.com.

Skydrive was working fine until a little while after I installed Win8.1, and everything stopped.  Is this some kind of Win8.1 bug?

**EDIT:**
I am using Windows 8.1 *Preview* on a Lenovo Computer that came with Windows 8

Comment: Most of your problems are because your using the preview which will be solved once you install Windows 8.1 RTM of course there is no upgrade path so backup your all your personal files before you so that

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 8.1 the files are not synced/downloaded by default. You need to select which files/folders you want to have offline on your PC.

https://blog.onedrive.com/skydrive-introduces-smart-files-in-windows-8-1/

Comment: @Robotnik I fixed the link.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that "Access all files offline" is turned on in the options for Skydrive (with skydrive open, swipe from right and click on "Options")